# Stack and heap memory when array is initialized in java

Tags: java, arrays, memory, heap-memory, stack-memory

I have a question about where in memory arrays are stored when arrays are initialized.

I understand that local variables and method parameters are stored in stack; objects are stored in heap.

What I am wondering is if an array is initialized, is there a difference where they are stored in below cases?
Assume they are in the main method.

```
int[] a = {1,2,3,4,5};
int[] b = new int[a.length];
```

Thank you for your answer :)

Comment: I'm pretty sure the answer is no.  Both of those arrays are stored in the heap.  Arrays are objects so they always go on the heap.

Answer (score -1):

There should not be any difference in both since both are stored in heap. You could check link [what does a java array look like in memory](https://www.programcreek.com/2013/04/what-does-a-java-array-look-like-in-memory/)